# how can i calculate the length of a string in 4-byte unsigned long in network order (big endian) in Java

Tags: java

I'm stuck with this. I have to send messages to a server to receive the data that I need. 
There is a field after the message's header which is "Length":

> The length is the total number of bytes in the payload, which includes
>   all instances of the Param and Delim fields and excludes the header
>   and framing characters. The length is a 4-byte unsigned long in
>   network order (big endian).

The only two examples in the documentation are these:

if payload is

> 5022=LoginUser|5028=abc|5029=def|5026=1

the length field is

> <0x00><0x00><0x00><0x27>

if payload is

> 5022=Subscribe|4=558|5026=2

the length field is

> <0x00><0x00><0x00><0x1B>

I've tried some approaches without success. Any idea on how to handle with this would be very appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final byte[] data = string.getBytes("utf-8");
int length = data.length;
final byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
bytes[3] = (byte) length;
bytes[2] = (byte) length >>> 8;
bytes[1] = (byte) length >>> 16;
bytes[0] = (byte) length >>> 24;
```

Comment: `int length = string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length;`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some `OutputStream out` and `String payload`:

```
DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(out);
byte[] payloadBytes = payload.getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
dataOut.writeInt(payloadBytes.length);
dataOut.write(payloadBytes);
```